# How do I grant the "editor" role only on one or two specific Google Cloud Compute Engine Instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have one person (a) who is in charge of administrating our Windows instances on Google Cloud and another person manages our Ubuntu instances. I want to allow the first person to have permission to start, stop, reset, change metadata / instance-size and login as admin on the Windows instances, but I don't want them to have access to perform those actions on any of the Ubuntu instances. All of the instances are part of the same project.

Is there any way to grant such permissions at an instance-level, without granting them for all instances in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having trouble finding a way to do this because it is not available from the "IAM" section on Google Cloud. However, you can assign instance-specific roles and permissions form the Cloud Engine - VM Instances Page:

1. Go to the Computer Engine VM Instances page: https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances
2. Click the checkbox beside the instance(s) to which you want to assign instance-specific roles.
3. Click on "Show Info Panel".
4. On the "Info Panel" on the right side of the screen under "Permissions" click "Add Members".
5. Select the members / roles you want to assign and click "Save".

Answer (score 1):

GCP allows one to provide fine grained permissions on Compute Engine instances.  This appears to be well documented in the documentation found at:

[Granting access to Compute Engine resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/granting-access-to-resources)

At the highest level, we can assign permissions either through Cloud Console or through the `gcloud` command.

Answer (score 1):

Google Compute Engine supports specifying the service account to use for the instance.

I recommend creating a new service account, assigning the Project Editor role and then assign that service account to instances that require this level of permission.

I do not recommend using Compute Engine Scopes to control permissions. Specify the desired roles for the service account, assign the service account to Compute Engine and specify "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs". The actual permissions will be controlled by the service account roles. Scopes are too granular in some cases.

I wrote an article that dives deeper into Compute Engine service accounts.

[Google Cloud – Compute Engine Service Accounts](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-compute-engine-service-accounts/)